# perform a task when android automation pass or fail (robotium)

Tags: android, junit, automation, robotium

I am trying to perform a task when android is fail or pass, is there a way to do this,  and where should I put my code?

was thinking to do it in tearDown, but is there a way to check whether the testcase is pass or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I've found the solution.

we can override the runTest() method,  and do this:

```
    super.runTest():
    doSomething()
```

doSomething() will be executed when test passed..

Answer (score 1):

When your test fails - that is an exception which is thrown.
I would suggest you to put the code related to your test case in try/catch block and in catch block do the stuff you want to do on test failure.

In order to mark that test case as failure you can throw the exception at the end of catch block.

e.g:

```
try
{
solo.....
//do your stuff
}
catch(Throwable e)
{
//Do what you want to do on test failure.
throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a test listener to get the pass or fail stance automatically, this however is a little bit of a pain, you will either need to override your instrumentation test runner, or use reflection to get the AndroidTestRunner from your current instrumentation test runner and then you can add in the listener as seen here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestRunner.html

There are other ways too but they are all a little bit of manual work (such as catching assertion exceptions within test methods and doing failure case that way.